# Executing custom management commands return None

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create custom management command which will execute data from Api. I wrote this code:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from data.models import Country
import requests 
import json

def extracting():
    country_req = requests.get("https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/countries", headers = {"X-RapidAPI-Key": "my_token"})
    parsed_string =  json.loads(country_req.text)


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, **options):
        print(extracting())
```

but, when I try to execute it with `python manage.py extract` in my console I see None, while when I try to run this code in console without custom management command I see data which I try to execute.

Any ideas?

Comment: you see None because extracting() does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

You do not return anything from the `extracting()` method. Depending on your interactive console, you might see the values for variables. But what you probably want to do is:

```
def extracting():
    country_req = requests.get("https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/countries", headers = {"X-RapidAPI-Key": "my_token"})
    return json.loads(country_req.text)
```